# I use OR to form a multiple condition IF ELSE statement on VBA, it's not working

Tags: vba, if-statement, multiple-conditions

```
Dim cat As Integer
For cat = 2 To last
    Range("AB" & cat).Select

    If Selection.Value = " " Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "-"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "-"

    ElseIf Selection.Value = "Address in local wording" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Customer"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Incomplete information or awaiting more info from customer"

    ElseIf (Selection.Value = "hold to console" Or "Hold to console" Or "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day") Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Depot"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Allotment delay"

    ElseIf (Selection.Value = "Backorder" Or "backorder" Or "Back order" Or "back order") Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Inventory"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Material not available causing backorder"

    End If        
Next cat
```

The result I get is when Selection.Value is empty,  **`"-" , "-"`** 
and the rest all show **`"Depot"`** , **`"Allotment delay"`** only.

What's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the line below is incorrect:

```
ElseIf (Selection.Value = "hold to console" Or "Hold to console" Or "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day") Then
```

You need to add `Selection.Value =` before each condition, see line below:

```
ElseIf Selection.Value = "hold to console" Or Selection.Value = "Hold to console" Or Selection.Value = "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day" Then
```

Note: the same applies to all other `ElseIf`s you have.

---

***Edit 1***

However,I would suggest to use the code below. Your code is "screaming" for `Select Case`. Also, there is no need to `Range("AB" & cat).Select` and later use `ActiveCell`, instead you could just use fully qualifed `Range`.

**Code**

```
Dim cat As Long

For cat = 2 To last
    Select Case Range("AB" & cat).Value
        Case " "
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -2).Value = "-"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -1).Value = "-"

        Case "Address in local wording"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Customer"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Incomplete information or awaiting more info from customer"

        Case "hold to console", "Hold to console", "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Depot"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Allotment delay"

        Case "Backorder", "backorder", "Back order", "back order"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Inventory"
            Range("AB" & cat).Offset(0, -1).Value = "Material not available causing backorder"
    End Select

Next cat
```

Comment: @lcc see answer and code under **Edit 1**, I think this is the way you should adapt to your code

Comment: Do you have an explanation for how the original code was even _running_?  I couldn't reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to express equality in each condition.  In other words, instead of this:

```
(Selection.Value = "hold to console" Or
 "Hold to console" Or
 "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day") Then
```

you need to use this:

```
(Selection.Value = "hold to console" Or
 Selection.Value = "Hold to console" Or
 Selection.Value = "Allocated 14/12 and ship next day") Then
```