# how do I include a range of columns to create a Marlett checkbox using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following VBA code to create a Marlett check box where the cell itself becomes a checkbox rather than inserting a checkbox.  However the code only applies to one column (column D in this isntance).  How do i write the code so that I can apply the same function to Columns E, F, G and H also?

```
VBA Code:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Cancel = True
            If .Value = "a" Then
                .Value = vbNullString
            Else
                .Value = "a"
                .Font.Name = "Marlett"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently by adjusting the `If .Column = 4` condition accordingly?

Comment: @GSerg, It's the accordingly bit I am struggling with.  i am a complete novice to VBA

Comment: If you had `If x = 5` and `If x = 6`, and you wanted `x` to be either 5 or 6, would you know how to combine that into a single `If`?

Comment: I would have assumed it would be a matter of 
'If .Column = "15" & "16" Then' 
however this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Which is to be expected as `&` is the [string concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator). The logical disjunction operator is [`Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/or-operator). But before you simply replace one with another, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42803797/11683.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim v
    'within required range?
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E:H")) Is Nothing Then
        v = Target.Value
        Target.Value = IIf(v = "a", vbNullString, "a")
        Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
        Cancel = True '<< don't enter edit mode
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The font was not set when it was "a".

Comment: @GSerg - I did notice that, but figured since it wasn't *unset* when unchecking, that it didn't matter.